# How to use the Google Fit API in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, api, http, google-fit

What are the steps needed to include the Google Fit API inside an Xcode project using swift.

I already used the documentation given by Google but it is very complex to understand everything right. With the OAuth Playground I successfully sent some requests to get data of my selected Google account. While using the OAuth Playground a so called Access Token is being created and with the use of it I am also able to call the exact same request via curl in my terminal.

Now I want to call the exact same thing inside my Xcode project in swift. I already created a very simple project and included the functionality to call the wanted request as shown in this code snippet:

```
/ Create URL
    let url = URL(string: "https://fitness.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources/derived:com.google.heart_rate.bpm:com.google.android.gms:merge_heart_rate_bpm/datasets/1681711200000000000-1681887600000000000")
    guard let requestUrl = url else { fatalError() }

    // Create URL Request
    var request = URLRequest(url: requestUrl)

    // Specify HTTP Method to use
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    
    // Set header information
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("Bearer ya29.<Access Token>", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    // Send HTTP Request
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        
        // Check if Error took place
        if let error = error {
            print("Error took place \(error)")
            return
        }
        
        // Read HTTP Response Status code
        if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            print("Response HTTP Status code: \(response.statusCode)")
        }
        
        // Convert HTTP Response Data to a simple String
        if let data = data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("Response data string:\n \(dataString)")
        }
        
    }
    task.resume()
```

Now I want to know how to get this so called Access Token which is used in the Header of the HTTP request in the Authorization field. The one I pasted there from the OAuth Playground is working but how do I create or get one without the OAuth Playground. How do you authenticate a user inside the iOS app/project to the Google Fit API?

Does anyone know the necessarily steps?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You will need an oauth client in your app to allow a user to authenticate and obtain the token. There are several free and open source implementations available.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Do you have any helpful links? I already implemented the Google Log-in given in the official documentation. But after receiving the **ID-token** I don't know how to request the **access token**

Comment: You could use [Google SignIn](https://developers.google.com/identity/#google-sign-in) or [an oauth](https://oauth.net/code/swift/) library

Comment: I already implemented this [Google SignIn](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/people?hl=en) but in chapter _Authenticate with backend server_ I don't know how to get the **acces token** with the previously received **ID-token**. To which URL do I need to send my POST request for getting an access token?

Comment: You can get the token from the `user` - https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api-access